# regex_replace by a var content in jinja template

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a jinja template and i want to replace a string by the content of a variable

exemple :

```
ansible_hostname: 'host-to'
item.suffixe: 'cool'
```

the result will be : host-cool-to

I did this :

`{{ ansible_hostname | regex_replace('-to', '-{{ item.suffixe }}-to') }}`

of course the '-{{ item.suffixe }}-to' was not interpreted and the result is :
host-{{ item.suffixe }}-to

Is it possible to use a variable in regex_replace ? How ? in the ansible exemple they don't show anythings like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: *"Is it possible to use a variable in regex_replace ?"*

A: Yes. It's possible. It's easier to put the parameters into variables. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostname | regex_replace(regex, replace) }}"
      vars:
        hostname: host-to
        suffix: cool
        regex: '-to'
        replace: '-{{ suffix }}-to'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: host-cool-to
```